# What does "DMC" mean?

Tags: terminology, digital, panasonic

I have seen "DMC" in many names of digital cameras. Is this an abbreviation? What does it mean?

Some examples:

- [Lumix DMC-TZ40](http://www.photographyblog.com/reviews/panasonic_lumix_dmc_tz40_review)
- [DMC-FZ200](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/panasonic-lumix-dmc-fz200)
- [DMC FT25](http://www.panasonic.com/de/consumer/foto-video/lumix-kompaktkameras/dmc-ft25.html)

Comment: Is this with respect to camcorders?

Comment: JoanneC: I have only seen this for Panasonic compact cameras (I think they all have the ability to make movies, but that does not make them a camcorder, does it?)

Comment: the consensus seems to be d=digital and c=camera, but the m can be mirror, micro, media, manual or anything else the manufacturers marketing department picks from the air.

Answer (score 5):

DMC stands for "Digital Media Camera" although a panasonic dealer told me it means "Digital Still Camera"

Comment: Was the panasonic dealer a former Sony dealer? (; sounds more like their DSC acronym.

Comment: @drfrogsplat exactly, maybe he got confused

Answer (score 3):

DMC is just a model code used by Panasonic for their "Lumix" cameras.  It doesn't have a technical meaning other than appearing as part of their internal product codes on all Lumix cameras.

You may speculate about what the letters stand for and Panasonic may even tell you what they stand for, but it's a meaning that's not technical, but just part of the way Panasonic identifies their model names.  They had to choose some sequence of letters or numbers to identify their Lumix cameras, and they happened to choose the letters DMC for some reason.

[This](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/34284314) indicates that it stands for "Digital Media Camera" but that could well be post-rationalization.  It could also depend on which Panasonic representative you ask.

They have other codes for other product lines, for example their televisions have "TX" in the model code.

Answer (score 1):

Given that Panasonic applies these to digital cameras, I believe that's an acronym for a "Digital Media Camera" designation. I'll base that on their electric shaver models starting with an ES.

Answer (score -2):

DMC= Digital Mirrorless Camera

Comment: I don't think so. The [Panasonic Lumix DMC-L1](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/Panasonicdmcl1) was a DSLR, mirror and all.