# What is the difference between Panasonic Lumix FZ1000 and Panasonic DMC-Lumix FZ1000

Tags: terminology

I am looking at the cameras Panasonic Lumix FZ1000 and Panasonic Lumix DMC-FZ1000. Are they the same camera? What are the features that makes them different, if that is the case.

Comment: vtc b/c - They're the same camera.

Comment: If you are happy with an answer please accept it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

`DMC` or no `DMC` it looks like both cameras are the same camera, so I don't think it's something that you need to be concerned about, same camera = same features.

I did some research and seems like `DMC` is part of the model number/name that Panasonic uses for this camera.

I found this post on what `DMC` might stand for - `digital media camera`:

[What does "DMC" mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/49043/what-does-dmc-mean)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same camera. Different sellers sometime name it Panasonic Lumix FZ1000 or Panasonic Lumix FZ-1000 but as far as I know the formal name is Panasonic Lumix DMC-FZ1000 (as it is on the Panasonic web site)

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely nothing. This is the same camera. All [Panasonic "Lumix"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumix) still image cameras officially have a "DMC-" prefix ahead of the "marketing" model number.

Comment: I upvoted to offset the downvote. The answer doesn't really add anything, but it probably was written at the same time as Romeo Ninov's answer.

Comment: @EricShain Thanks. It does add the information that *all* Panasonic Lumix still image cameras have a DMC- prefix in their official model number. It also includes a link to a list of Lumix model numbers at the Wikipedia page for 'Lumix.'

Comment: I agree with @MichaelClark, for me the answer did add value and shouldn't have been down voted.